# Single Sign-On using Azure AD with both Kentico 9 and SharePoint Online

Tags: kentico

Anyone seen or tried using Azure AD as both login for Kentico and SharePoint Online?  The question is how well it works or do the users tend to still have to log into both even using Azure AD?

Also do you know if there is a way to get an auto-login in Kentico to connect with Azure AD?  Kind of assuming it would take some custom implementation but just wondering if anyone else has done anything around this?